# Execute a bash command using script variable, Which contains path with space to the executable tool?

Tags: bash, android-build

I am writing a small script which will generate the signed apk.

I have android build tools located at

```
C:/Users/Fname Lname/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk/build-tools/27.0.3/
```

Within these build tools folder `27.0.3` there is `apksigner.bat` file which is the tool to sign an apk file.

I am copying this file in an array which contains a set of commands for me,

```
cmd[1]="C:/Users/Fname Lname/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk/build-tools/27.0.3/apksigner.bat"
```

Actual signing operation happens using the command as below,

```
"${cmd[1]}" sign --ks "$PATH_TO_JKS_KEY" --out "$outputfile" "$inputfile"
```

Above command fails with the following message,

```
'C:\Users\Fname' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

I think the problem is space between Fname Lname in the path to the command.

Surprisingly the other command works exactly in this way, as follows

```
cmd[0]="C:/Users/Fname Lname/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk/build-tools/27.0.3/zipalign"
"${cmd[0]}" -v -p 4 "$inputfilepath" "$outputfilepath"
```

This command path also has space between Fname & Lname.

**Environment:**

```
Windows 10
Command runs under git bash.
```

What might be wrong?

**Update 1**

As per the suggestion of [Nahuel Fouilleul](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1454708/nahuel-fouilleul) in the comment section, I added below code prior to my erroneous code

```
printf "'%s'\n" "${cmd[@]}"
set -x
```

Following result came onto the screen,

```
    'C:/Users/Fname Lname/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk/build-tools/27.0.3/zipalign'
'C:/Users/Fname Lname/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk/build-tools/27.0.3/apksigner.bat'
+ echo ''

+ echo 'ANDROID Apk sign operation in progress'
ANDROID Apk sign operation in progress
+ 'C:/Users/Fname Lname/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk/build-tools/27.0.3/apksigner.bat' sign --ks 'C:\Projects\Dummy\app/my-app/upload_android.jks' --out '/c/Users/Fname Lname/Desktop/cmd_test/test/20-Nov-2018_18-36-14_IST/my-app-release.apk' '/c/Users/Fname Lname/Desktop/cmd_test/test/20-Nov-2018_18-36-14_IST/my-app-release-zipalign.apk'
'C:\Users\Fname' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
+ '[' 1 '!=' 0 ']'
+ echo 'Android apk signing failed'
Android apk signing failed
+ abortRestore gyh5dd9e65ba174f44cd2fe92c4093ed240cda06
+ git reset --hard gyh5dd9e65ba174f44cd2fe92c4093ed240cda06
HEAD is now at gyh5dd9 This is restore point test case
+ '[' 0 '!=' 0 ']'
+ exit 1
```

**Update 2**

After comments by [Charles Duffy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/14122/charles-duffy) I tried running on Mac it worked well also I came across one more problem as I used windows editor software ( Notepad++ ) which added a \r (carriage return) to the end of every line, causing script execution failure ( [Link to carriage return issue](https://superuser.com/questions/813346/bash-scripts-are-not-working-but-on-mac-terminal-those-commands-in-scripts-works) ), So now I have decided to start working on the script on Mac machine instead of windows.

Important comment by Charles :

*basically, calling Windows applications with escaped names requires knowing how that specific application unescapes its command line, because on Windows, each program is responsible for parsing a string passed to it as a command line into its argument list; by contrast, on UNIX, programs are started with an array, not a single string... so a Windows portability layer needs to guess at how to change the array of separate strings passed to the execv family of UNIX syscalls into a single string in a way the native-Windows called program will understand.*

Comment: it seems the command is not exactly run as it is in question, can you add following commands before `"${cmd[1]}" ...` call : `printf "'%s'\n" "${cmd[@]}"` and `set -x`

Comment: @NahuelFouilleul pls have look at the updated question, Thanks

Comment: `printf '%s\n'` isn't particularly useful -- it just provides the literal content; literal quotes will at least allow CR detection, but not all nonprintable/invisible characters are carriage returns. If the shell is bash, `printf '%q\n' "$@"` is much more relevant/applicable, insofar as it emits the content with nonprintable values visually distinguished. (Baseline POSIX `/bin/sh` doesn't support that operation, so whether the shell *really is* bash is pertinent).

Comment: ...the other thing is that this smells like we have some platform-specific weirdness here. On a real UNIXlike platform, `'C:/Users/Fname Lname/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk/build-tools/27.0.3/apksigner.bat'` wouldn't be treating `C:/Users/Fname` as its own word. Do you have a Linux VM? Might make sense just to use it, and get Windows out-of-the-picture.

Comment: ...basically, calling Windows applications with escaped names requires knowing *how that specific application* unescapes its command line, because on Windows, each program is responsible for parsing a string passed to it as a command line into its argument list; by contrast, on UNIX, programs are started with an array, not a single string... so a Windows portability layer needs to guess at how to change the array of separate strings passed to the `execv` family of UNIX syscalls into a single string in a way the native-Windows called program will understand.

Comment: Because each program on Windows can do this parsing differently (*most* use the libc default implementation, but not all do), converting into a format that will correctly parse back to the original array is necessarily guesswork, and it's necessary error-prone.

Comment: ...which is to say -- your script, as far as I can tell, is fine. The bugs are in the tools you're using, and switching to Linux would avoid needing them at all.

Comment: @Charles Duffy thanks for the detailed explanation I will set up one Linux environment with Android build tools and execute the script once & let you know the results,